# WiFi gets connected but internet doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, internet

I currently have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my laptop. The WiFi gets connected without any problem but when I try to get internet access it becomes impossible. It works fine with a wireless usb toggle connection. Internal wireless module doesn't work properly

What can I do to fix this?
My laptop is Toshiba satellite A500

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 03
   serial: 00:26:22:4a:8f:a0
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:45 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f2004000-f2004fff memory:f2000000-f2003fff memory:f2020000-f203ffff

   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:14:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:23:08:e9:ba:6a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:19 memory:f6000000-f600ffff

   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@2:1
   logical name: wlan1
   serial: 74:ea:3a:8b:05:60
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.2.5 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Which device is not working? Both require firmware, did you install it? What does `dmesg` show?

Comment: Ateros doesn't work properly but i can connect internet with external wifi adapter and wire connection